The extension .ts is not working in the microservices
i am creating api. using the microservices and managing the services with pm2 but when i start the server i am getting the error
➜  ecommercbackend git:(main) ✗ npm start

> Ecommerce Backend@1.0.0 start
> ts-node -T -P tsconfig.json app.ts

TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for /Volumes/DATA-2/nodejs/microservices-node/ecommercbackend/app.ts
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)
    at Object.getFileProtocolModuleFormat [as file:] (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:136:11)
    at defaultGetFormat (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:182:36)
    at defaultLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/load:101:20)
    at ModuleLoader.load (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:417:13)
    at ModuleLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:288:22)
    at new ModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:63:26)
    at ModuleLoader.#createModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:312:17)
    at ModuleLoader.getJobFromResolveResult (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:265:34)
    at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:251:17) {
  code: 'ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION'
}

I want to solve this problem and want to build my backend with the microservice and typescript
here is my tsconfig.json
{"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
    "sourceMap": true,                       
    "outDir": "./build",

    "strict": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,

    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,

    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "types": ["reflect-metadata"],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "inlineSources": true,

    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
}}

and here is my
{   "name": "Ecommerce Backend",   "version": "1.0.0",   "type": "module",   "main": "app.ts",   "scripts": {     "start": "ts-node -T -P tsconfig.json app.ts"   },   "author": "lalit patidar",   "license": "ISC",   "description": "",   "dependencies": {     "bcrypt": "^5.1.1",     "body-parser": "^1.20.2",     "chalk": "^5.3.0",     "cors": "^2.8.5",     "dotenv": "^16.4.5",     "express": "^4.19.2",     "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",     "mailtrap": "^3.3.0",     "mongodb": "^6.7.0",     "mongoose": "^8.4.4",     "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",     "nodemailer": "^6.9.14",     "nodemon": "^3.1.4",     "validator": "^13.12.0"   },   "devDependencies": {     "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.2",     "@types/cors": "^2.8.17",     "@types/express": "^4.17.21",     "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.6",     "@types/mongoose": "^5.11.97",     "@types/multer": "^1.4.11",     "@types/node": "^20.14.14",     "@types/validator": "^13.12.0",     "ts-node": "^10.9.2",     "typescript": "^5.5.4"   } }   

please give me some solution
